# Regular Expression: match "ComponentNumber_componentName_componentPart(optional)"

Tags: c#, regex

I am having difficulty with the following for a regular expression match:

"ComponentNumber_componentName_componentPart(optional)"

Where "ComponentNumber" is one letter followed by an indefinite length of numbers appended all the way until the first occurance of "_", then "componentName" is any set of text that may also contain multiple "_" 's. We go until we see the final "_" which contains nothing but optional text appended.

Could someone please assist?

E.g. of valid entries:

Y1122334455_Component_Text_Optional_Values

Q00998877_CompName1_Optional

S77889911_CName_1_Test_Optional_Values_2

Where when you see "Optional" as the indicator for anything after the third "_"

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an example with no optional component part? (Do you end with the final underscore?)

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can distinguish between `ComponentName` and `ComponentPart` because they are separated by an underscore and both may contain underscores. How do you determine when the optional `ComponentPart` starts, or if it even exists (vs. just being part of `ComponentName`)?

Comment: Ok so let's just leave out the optional part. Lets just match the ComponentName to match the first letter followed by an indefinite numbers, then anything that comes after the first underscore, I can use the .Contains method to see if the value I want appears inside. So I guess the regex for the first part would be ^[A-Z][0-9] but how do you make it so its indefinite? Thanks

Comment: See my answer below: you'll want to use a quantifier such as `+` meaning one or more times or `*` meaning zero or more times for the digit following the letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment on your question, it doesn't seem like you can distinguish between `ComponentName` and `ComponentPart` because they are separated by an underscore and both may contain underscores.

Based on your reply, you would use a pattern like:

`(?'ComponentNumber'[A-Za-z]\d+)_(?'ComponentName'.+)`

[image: Regex Diagram]

To match the `ComponentNumber` and then everything following the first underscore as `ComponentName`.

Comment: Great. Thanks I will use this. The way I will match the rest is to take the string and split it on all the '_' values inside a string array. I will check the string array value at index 0 and see if it matches the first regular expression "(^[a-zA-Z]\d+)". Then I will look in the rest of the items in the array and see if they match 'ComponentName' I am looking for after index 0 using the .Contains method.

Comment: Also btw, where do you go to try regex expressions and embed them in your answers like above? Is this a place I can build my own expressions? Thanks

Comment: You can use this web page to build diagrams from regular expressions: http://www.regexper.com/  It may help you understand a pattern, but it doesn't help you build them.  A Google Search for "regular expression helper" yields many web pages and tools that help build expressions.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that might get you started:

```
([a-zA-Z]\d+)_(.+)_(\w+)
```

It does the following:

[image: Regex visualisation]

This will match the following:

```
 Y1122334455_Component_Text_Optional_Values:
(Y1122334455, Component_Text_Optional, Values)

 Q00998877_CompName1_Optional
(Q00998877, CompName1, Optional)

S77889911_CName_1_Test_Optional_Values_2
(S77889911, CName_1_Test_Optional_Values, 2)
```

Something tells me this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi thank you for the very nice description and answer format. Everything that you have put down is correct, except that anything that has optional in the third match should not be contained in the second match. i.e. (Y1122334455, Component_Text_Optional, Values) should be (Y1122334455, Component_Text, Optional_Values).